# What is the simplest way to integrate screencasts with trello in the fewest number of steps in OSX?

Tags: macos, quicktime, screencasts, trello

What is the simplest means for opening a trello card, and creating from within it a screencast which will be attached to it?

The goal is seamless attachment of a 5- 10 second screencast which makes tangible the trello item ( in this case its for trello items which are tasks ).

Answer (score 0):

I can share my current best approach to this, although I know someone has created a better one ( thus the question )

## Setup

Download google drive for mac
https://www.google.com/drive/download/

Sync a folder on your computer to that google drive remote

Download and install Alfred for mac
https://www.alfredapp.com/

Download the screen capture plugin for alfred
[screen capture plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXX0J.png)

Create a custom screen capture workflow that triggers the start of a screen cast and set it to save to the synced google drive folder
[workflow customization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jivNg.png)

[workflow part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b18Yh.png)

[workflow part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oC238.png)

## Implementation

Now, to use this workflow, I now have access to alfred to trigger the recording of the screen capture, when it saves it will auto sync with the google drive folder providing me a link to the screen cast... which I will paste into the trello card...

So, while in trello, I open a card, and to describe it further with a screencast, I trigger alfred, plug in the shortcut for my custom alfred workflow... sv  - that launches a screen capture, which I use to expand on the trello card description in 5-10 seconds, and then when I save it, it auto populate